# Get rid of Babel(StandAlone) warning message from CDN package

Tags: reactjs, console, babeljs, warnings, cdn

We are using React JS CDN for certain sections in our project. For quality purpose, we want to deliver warnings free code to the client.

We are using following libraries:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that we are getting the following warning message in console:

**You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production**

We know this is not much of a problem, but we do want to remove this warning from our web app console. Should we make any changes in code, or do anything else? Please guide, how to eradicate this warning message. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Babel Standalone is meant to be a convenient tool for *debugging and discussion* about code online (such as on Stack Overflow in Stack Snippets), but the method by which it works is quite inefficient - it's a large package, and transforming JSX to JS in the browser takes up a good chunk of the client's resources.

For production sites, the best approach here is to do as the warning recommends, and instead precompile your React's JSX to plain JavaScript, so that you can serve a single plain JavaScript file to clients. This way, the code only has to be compiled once, on your server's end, rather than on the client's end every time the client loads a page.

For an easy start to this process, consider [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#recommended-toolchains). You will need Node and NPM.

> When you’re ready to deploy to production, running `npm run build` will create an optimized build of your app in the `build` folder.

Then you only have to serve that, instead of making clients rely on also downloading and parsing React, React DOM, and Babel Standalone.

Comment: How can I add the build from "create-react-app" to certain sections of my overall project? If there's a way for that pleas guide. Thanks.

Comment: Read the [link in my answer](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#recommended-toolchains) which goes into detail on it. You can write a page with create-react-app, then serve the compiled files to the client when they go to that one page. See [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#create-react-app--) and [here](https://create-react-app.dev/).

Comment: The Babel documentation itself lists expected, valid use cases for running Babel for production code directly from within a web app.  https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone