# React and Babel CDN for production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

**Can I use React CDN and Babel Standalone CDN for production? For my small project.**

**React CDN**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
```

**Babel CDN**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bad idea. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68350422